# IE7 Responsive Image Glitch

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

So this is a weird one.

I'm working on a Wordpress theme, and the theme is supposed to be fully responsive. I created a "gallery" of sorts that consists of multiple rows of 3 thumbnails that when clicked open in a lightbox.  I found a snippet of code online for creating responsive "square" elements; elements whose height adjusts to match their responsive width using only CSS.  This involves setting a width in percentage (say 50%), and then setting `height:0px;` and `padding-bottom:50%;`.  I went ahead and placed every image in a responsive container that resize like this, and then I set the images max width and max height so they wouldn't overflow their responsive square container.

This displays as expected in all browsers save for ie7.  In ie7, the image seems to disappear.  I've attached a fiddle (not my exact code, but still causes the issue). http://jsfiddle.net/pwGYc/

Here's the actual code:

HTML:

```
<a href="<? echo $photo["url"]; ?>" class="photo" title="<? echo $photo["title"]; ?>">
    <img src="<? echo $photo["url"]; ?>" alt="<? echo $photo["alt"]; ?>" title="<? echo $photo["title"]; ?>" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.photo{
float:left;
margin:10px;
width:30%;
height:0px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:5px 0px 30% 0px !important;
box-sizing:border-box;
position:relative;
}

.photo img{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
margin:auto;
max-height:97%;
max-width:97%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support [border-box](http://www.snackoclock.net/2012/08/simple-box-sizing-border-box-fallback-for-ie/).
And you can not mix percents with absolute px values. So don't do width 30% and margin 10px. What's this in sum? 3 x 30% + 3 x 10px = maybe 1422px?
If you say margin 3% you can be sure of 3 x 30% + 3 x 3% = 99%

Comment: Border box wouldn't cause the contents of the box to disappear in ie7 would it?  The rule would simply be ignored.  Also, I'm not actually using percents in code like that but when I copied over I tried to compact and short hand.  I actually have `padding`:`5px 0px 5px 0px`, and then further down the rule I have `padding-bottom:30%`